# Best practices to make a library backwards compatible?

Tags: c#, architecture

I have a library of utility classes.  One of the classes performs file archiving similar to *tar* because .NET already has *gz*.

The archive class uses [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) for versioning, so it can support files compressed with older versions of this library.  Here is an example:

```
public void ExtractTo(DirectoryInfo directory, bool overwrite = false)
{
    // removed sanity checks, try/catch, etc. for brevity

    using (FileStream archiveStream = 
        new FileStream(this.archivefile.FullName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        byte[] magicNumber = new byte[8];
        archiveStream.Read(magicNumber, 0, 8);

        string ArchiveLib_Version = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(magicNumber);

        switch (ArchiveLib_Version)
        {
            case "ALib0000": 
                ExtractTo_v0(archiveStream, dirInfo);
                break;
            case "ALib0001":
                ExtractTo_v1(archiveStream, dirInfo);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IOException("Archive file invalid.");
        }
    }
}
```

But, the versioned methods depend on other routines in the library that may change in the future, for example my Stream.SubStream extension method:

```
protected void ExtractTo_v1(FileStream archiveStream, DirectoryInfo dirInfo)
{
    // ...

    foreach (ArchiveFileInfo arcInfo in archiveHeader)
    {
        Stream sourceBytes = archiveStream.SubStream(
            arcInfo.archivePosition, arcInfo.archiveLength);

        using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(sourceBytes, 
            CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to version the entire library, create a list of dependent methods, do something else?

What's the best practice for maintaining backwards compatibility in a library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two broad options:

**Modify Existing Code while Maintaining Backwards Compatibility**

You can go ahead and modify the implementation of `SubStream` (and other dependent methods) for newer versions of your archive. This approach can help minimize the amount of duplicated code in your codebase, helping you adhere to the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

[Unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) can be used to ensure that `SubStream` (and other dependent methods) continue to work for old archive versions. You could write a set of tests that call `SubStream` with a [mock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) stream that provides old archive data, and ensure that it gives you the expected results. When you change the implementation `SubStream` for new archive versions, a suite of tests can give you confidence that you haven't broken it for old archive versions.

The downside here is that you have to spend the effort on maintaining a suite of tests.

**OR**

**Write New Code For New Versions And Leave Old Code Alone**

This approach is modeled on the [Open/Closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). If your `SubStream` method is closed to modification, it will therefore never break. If you need new or different functionality from your `SubStream` method for a new archive version, you could simply write a new `SubStream` method for the new format, and keep using the old, untouched `SubStream` method for the old format.

This can be much less effort than the above option - there's no need for comprehensive regression testing, just go ahead and write new code for your new feature and call it a day. The downside is that you may end up with duplicated code in your codebase. This could be a problem if you discover a defect that affects multiple versions of your methods - you will have to find and fix the bug in each version, rather than just fixing it in one place.

Which approach you take is entirely up to you :)